# NullPointerException in quartz cron job

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have problem with cron job implemented using Quartz Scheduler. It throws NullPointerException. This problem occurs only on server so I can't debug it. This is stacktrace:

```
[org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] Job myExampleJobs.simple job threw an unhandled 
Exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.schedule.JobScheduler.autowireProcessor(JobScheduler.java:269)
    at com.example.schedule.Job.execute(Job.java:17)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

`JobScheduler` class doesn't have 269 lines and doesn't have `autowireProcessor` method. Maybe this is method from Spring framework? I couldn't find anything about such method.
Maybe problem concerns autowired classes in SimpleJob or in JobScheduler?

Comment: com.example.schedule.JobScheduler is not your code ??

Comment: What do you mean "I can't debug it". You can, you just have to want it strongly enough. Connect to the server using remote debug:)

Comment: if com.example.schedule.JobScheduler is your code and your local code do not have line 269, your source seems different from your server

Comment: @farmer1992 `JobScheduler` is not my code but is isn't also class from quartz library. This is my colleague class.

Comment: @woyaru this must be something wrong with that file, you can download the .class and javap it to see what might be null at that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different version of the file, in the line

```
com.example.schedule.JobScheduler.autowireProcessor
```

seems like you have copy paste this code from somewhere and your accessing some example code which has a different version of the source.

Provide the more code if possible.

Comment: I haven't copied and pasted this code from somewhere. As I have described in comment to my question simply I am not the author of this class. The resolution of this NullPointerException is that application is building by automat and as it turns out latest changes in this class haven't been included in new build.